# If $1-a$ and $1-b$ are nilpotent, then show that $1-ab$ is nilpotent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Show that $1-ab$ is nilpotent. I have tried to solve this problem. I wonder if I've done it right. Does it seems correct?

[image]

Comment: I wonder with your definition. It shiuld be: $a$ is nillpotent if $a^n=0$ for some (fixed) $n$. So, your proof is not valid

Comment: We assume that (1-a) and (1-b) are nilpotent. @Jlamprong

Comment: @Ashleyjonsson In that case, what they meant was that $(1-a)^n = 0$ for a fixed $n$, not just any $n$, and likewise for $1-b$. Your proof assumes $(1-a)^k = 0$ for all $k$, which is not correct. You should be able to fix it though.

Comment: +1 to the comment of @Ashleyjonsson.

Also, OP could simplify the proof by noting that $(a(1-b))^m = 0$, so it is enough to show that if $c^n = 0 = d^m$, then $(c+d)^{m+n-1} = 0$.

Comment: @AlexG. If $x^n=0$ then $x^k=0$ for "almost every" $k$, in particular for every $k\ge n$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich indeed! This insight is a big hint toward a correct proof. Use the binomial theorem in the same way as OP, and take big enough exponents that you know that one or the other of the factors is zero in each term of the sum

Comment: Actually OP takes a large enough exponent already. So they just need to explain which factor is zero for each $k$, and why

Answer (score 3):

Alternative proof: In a commutative ring the subset of nilpotent elements is the so called nilradical $N(R)$, and it is the intersection of all prime ideal, i.e. $$N(R) = \bigcap_{\mathbb{q} \  \text{prime ideal}}\mathbb{q}$$ Therefore $N(R)$, as the intersection of ideals, is an ideal. As you noticed, $1-ab = 1-a + a(1-b)$ but $$1-a \in N(R)$$$$1-b \in N(R)$$ and so $$1-ab \in N(R) $$ This implies that $1-ab$ is nilpotent.

Comment: If we wish to use this proof, we will also need to show that $N(R)$ really is the set of all nilpotent elements of $R$.

Comment: @AlexG.: you are right, but this is a well-known fact, probably the proof is here on mathstack

Comment: That proof is harder that the problem itself.